# My transaction in Multibit HD has seen by 124 peers but yet after 11 hours, not confirmed?

Tags: multibit, unconfirmed-transactions

my transaction size is 1850 (bytes) with fee of 0.00051 BTC and it is seen by 124 peers in multibit HD . 
but now after 11 hours, it is not confirmed!
in blockchain.info it said "Estimated Confirmation Time: Very Soon (High Priority)"
why it is not confirmed?
here's the hash:
4fba9205ed407f941a35ebb4f8e56ee565625d3a55da903bfae4c95dbe1548b1
thanks

Comment: it got confirmed finally after 20 hours! i think it was the bitcoin network issue, cause in that moment there were about 50K unconfirmed transactions in blockchain.info

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [it was included in block #441,666](https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/4fba9205ed407f941a35ebb4f8e56ee565625d3a55da903bfae4c95dbe1548b1) and currently has 29 confirmations.

Answer (score 0):

The higher the number of unconfirmed transactions (in the mempool) the longer will take to confirm your transaction unless you give a higher fee.

I recommend watching current [mempool](https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/) where you can see the number of unconfirmed transactions and it gives you an idea how "clogged up" is the Bitcoin network.